# How to get NetworkImageView resource URL in String format?

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I loaded one image from server using **Volley** to `NetworkImageView`, now I want to get this image **URL String** value programmatically.

How I can do this ?

This image **URL** is dynamic like `http://example.com/img2.png`.

I tested `getResources()` and  `getBackground()` and other ways but I can't get this value.